# How to store a few values in Wordpress database

Tags: wordpress

My Wordpress website needs to retrieve a handful of strings and integers from another website and use the retrieved values when constructing every page.

I am planning to use WP Cron facility to run a PHP function to retrieve the values. I'd like to store them in the Wordpress database. Is there a standard way of doing this? Should I create my own table for this? Use an existing table? What Wordpress APIs should I use to read and write the data?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create your own table , and to connect to word press database , you should listen to `action hooks` then in function.php file you will find $wpdb; global object you can connect to database using this object

Example in `function.php` file

```
function doSomeThing(){
  global $wpdb;

  // write your logic here ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This will work perfectly. You may want to add a link to https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb to your answer.